# Removed Mac OS X by mistake on dual boot system

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot

I had OS X Lion and Windows Vista installed on my iMac. I wanted to re-install my Lion and in the process I removed it but could not re-install it since Apple have removed it from Mac Store.

Now my Mac system has only Windows Vista. It boots with Vista only. I have to get back to Mac OS X.

- I have a DVD of Snow Leopard. When I insert it and hold <kbd>C</kbd> during startup, it ejects the drive again.
- I've tried starting into Recovery but <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> doesn't do anything. It boots into Windows Vista.
- I can boot into the Recovery system holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and I have  the option to reinstall Lion. When I click on it, it takes me to next screen with title Install Mac OS X. But I get an alert saying Mac OS 10.7 is not available.
- I checked Disk Utility also. There now I have Mac OS X Base System. I tried to check the restore tab but I am not able to do anything there.

Regards
Pankaj

Comment: Hm. That's bad. See [Reinstalling Mac OS X without original disc](http://superuser.com/questions/484507/reinstalling-mac-os-x-without-original-disc/484527#484527) for a couple of ideas on how to obtain an installer for OS X. You should be able to reinstall from a OS X Lion disk image, which you'd need to download "somewhere".

Comment: I have updated my question, please check last two points

Comment: Did you buy OS X Lion on the Mac App Store? If your Mac came with 10.6 and you didn't obtain Lion legally through the App Store, you can't restore your system.

Answer (score 1):

You will need access to another mac, a copy of lion, & a USB HDD (Not a USB stick, as some of those cannot be made to start a mac). Follow these instructions to write Lion to the USB HDD http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive

Backup anything you want to keep on Windows Vista as it will be deleted.

Boot from USB drive by holding down ALT on the keyboard at power-on. Reinstall Lion, making sure you use disk utility to wipe the disk before installation.

CD-ROM drives in macs of late have a very high failure rate.